# Make a matrix that outputs if an element of a vector is found in another vector in a fast way in R?

Tags: r, vector

Input

```r
v1 <- c(5, 1, 4, 1, 1)
v2 <- c(1, 2, 4)
```

Desired Output

```r
      1     2     4
5 FALSE FALSE FALSE
1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

I know I may use `expand.grid` and `which` but I can't figure this out.

Is using `apply` a fast way to do it?

EDIT : In fact I just need the sum of every column of the matrix (number of `TRUE`). How can I do this in an efficient way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `outer()`:

```
res <- outer(v1, v2, `==`)
rownames(res) <- v1
colnames(res) <- v2
res
##       1     2     4
## 5 FALSE FALSE FALSE
## 1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
## 4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
## 1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
## 1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If you're familiar with pipes, you can also do this without the multiple assignments:

```
library(magrittr)
outer(v1, v2, `==`) %>%
  set_rownames(v1) %>%
  set_colnames(v2)
```

Comment: Is there any faster function than `outer`?

Comment: In fact I just need the sum of every column of the matrix (number of `TRUE`). How can I do this in an efficient way ?

Comment: I foud `library(dplyr); expand.grid(v1, v2) %>% mutate(equal = Var1 == Var2) %>% group_by(Var2) %>% summarise(n = sum(equal))`

Comment: @Julien Well, taking the sum was not in your original question, so I'm not going to include it in my answer. You could just use the function `colSums()` on the matrix that I provided in my answer. Your solution works as well but is much slower for the  example that you give in the question.

Comment: Yes, my solution is slower, but your solution is still slower than a `for` loop with `which`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing in your for-loop, but this: `for (i in v2) sum(v1 == i)` is 60 times slower than using `outer()`. `outer()` should be fast because it's uses the fact that `==` is vectorised.

Comment: @Julien It's bad practice to change the question after the fact. Rather accept the best answer and open a new question.

Comment: The problem is that constructing the matrix takes time. I would need a solution that dos not require to construct the matrix

Comment: @Julien  You can always ask a new question.

Comment: I found a fast solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57079485/creating-a-vector-in-r-of-counts-for-number-of-times-each-element-appears-in-ano

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the sum of every column that is `TRUE`, you could do either of these:

```r
v1 <- c(5, 1, 4, 1, 1)
v2 <- c(1, 2, 4)

`colnames<-`(t(matrix(Map(\(x) sum( v1 %in% x), v2))), v2)
#>      1 2 4
#> [1,] 3 0 1

`colnames<-`(t(matrix(colSums(outer(v1, v2, `==`)))), v2)
#>      1 2 4
#> [1,] 3 0 1
```

Not sure of the speed of either of these.

Comment: I think the two solutions are too slow since  they use `Map` or `outer`